# Instagram API: how can I have multiple redirect_uris for a single app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm quite familiar with OAuth 2 for other providers, but haven't used it for Instagram before.

Like many developers, I have multiple domains where my app may run, eg:

```
 http://www.foo.com/oauth2callback
 https://www.foo.com/oauth2callback
 http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback
 https://localhost:3000/oauth2callback
```

[Other OAuth 2 providers I have used, eg, Google, allow multiple entries in a redirect_uris parameter](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

However [Instagram only seems to allow a single Redirect URI parameter per registered app](http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/).

Can I have multiple redirect URIs for a single Instagram app or do I have to register multiple apps, each with a different redirect URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like now you can set multiple **Redirect URL(s)** when you register/edit a Client in Instagram:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for keeping Stack up to date!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know if there is some limit to the number of redirect URIs? I need to set up a lot of different URIs one for each domain where my apps run.. http://hello.com/auth/instagram/callback , http://hi.com/auth/instagram/callback , http://bye.com/auth/instagram/callback , and so on...

Answer (score 6):

With Instagram apps that I have created, I have created a separate app per place I want to redirect to, although I haven't discriminated by ssl. I then load the api credentials into the app based on the environment it is running in.

It is a pain that you have to do that, as Instagram also restrict you to 5 registered apps per account too. It would be useful to be able register multiple redirects for that reason. But on the other hand, it would be just as good, for me, to not be restricted to the number of apps you can create (I've got more Twitter apps than I even remember creating!).

Comment: This is really bad. I read somewhere that one solution could be to create a "proxy" at the `redirect_uri` and redirect then to the proper place (thanks to query params that are sent back by Instagram). But I don't want to have to do so... Every other OAuth provider allows multiple redirect URIs..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those scenarios that you feel back in the Atari.

anyway, I found useful doing this one:

> edit your hosts file (in unix based OS: /etc/hosts)

make sure you add a line like this:

127.0.0.1 registeredomain.com

Where registeredomain.com is the domain you have in instagram as your production return uri.

In this way your app will return uri to registeredomain.com that is equivalent to localhost in your local machine, accepting the login.

btw: why? why? why? why instagram, why you have to force one return uri?  any reason for that?

Comment: can you please clarify this?

Comment: @kkomaz clear now? The ideal situation would be to have set up a development environment with an API Key with return uri to localhost, and a production environment with an API key with return uri to production url. But this is an easy workaround